# AzureCLI@2 Task - ADO Pipeline - change the default working directory

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, working-directory, dbt, cicd

I need help in changing the default working directory for my Azure CLI Task. The below code is not working for me.

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: 'dbt debug'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: XXXX
      ScriptType: bash
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      inlineScript: |
        dbt --version
        dbt debug --profiles-dir $(location) 
        workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
```

It throws the error - workingDirectory:: command not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It throws the error - workingDirectory:: command not found.

It seems that this is a YAML format issue.

You can try the sample:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: 'dbt debug'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: XXXX
      ScriptType: bash
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
      inlineScript: |
        dbt --version
        dbt debug --profiles-dir $(location)
```

Here is the doc about [Azure CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. The issue has been resolved.